# matrix homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Prove that $ϕ$ is a homomorphism and describe its kernel.
$$
ϕ:ℝ→GL(2,ℝ),\qquad
ϕ(x)=
\begin{bmatrix}\cos(2x)&\sin(2x)\\-\sin(2x)&\cos(2x)\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $x∈ℝ$

I have begun by saying 
$$
y=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(2y)&\sin(2y)\\-\sin(2y)&\cos(2y)\end{bmatrix} 
$$
$ℝ$ denote the set of real numbers under addition so I need to show that $ϕ(x+y)=ϕ(x)ϕ(y)$

So I have calculated 
$$
ϕ(x+y)\begin{bmatrix}\cos(2y)+\cos(2y)&\sin(2y)+\sin(2y)\\-\sin(2y)-\sin(2y)&\cos(2y)+\cos(2y)\end{bmatrix}
$$
Is this right? And I don't know how to go from there. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Note that by definition,
$$
\phi(x+y)=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(2(x+y)) & \sin(2(x+y)) \\
-\sin(2(x+y)) & \cos(2(x+y))
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now note that
\begin{align}
\cos(2x+2y)&=\cos(2x)\cos(2y)-\sin(2x)\sin(2y) \\
\sin(2x+2y)&=\sin(2x)\cos(2y)+\cos(2x)\sin(2y)
\end{align}
and compute
$$
\phi(x)\phi(y)=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(2x) & \sin(2x) \\
-\sin(2x) & \cos(2x)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(2y) & \sin(2y) \\
-\sin(2y) & \cos(2y)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
as a matrix product.

Comment: @ egreg: do I need to calculate the determinant of each and then multiply together? if so I did it but didn't get the same answer.

Comment: @jessica Why the determinant?

Comment: :Don't worry I've found it. But can you help me with finding the kernel?

Comment: @jessica The condition for $x\in\ker\phi$ is $\cos(2x)=1$ and $\sin(2x)=0$, so $\phi(x)$ is the identity matrix.